# how to work with asynctask in a loop?

Tags: android

I am saving some data in a database using asynctask with a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
new Loader().execute(i);
}
```

and in my asynctask class the doinbackground method is like this:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            db.insert(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
```

its being executed but everytime its inserting the first value of `i` in the database? how to work it with corresponding this loop?

Comment: Can't you execute AsyncTask once with multiple params?

Comment: I am new in asynctask , so i dont know much about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        int count = params.length;
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                db.insert(params[i]);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and you call `new Loader().execute(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

You save memory by creating only one `AsyncTask` object instance

Comment: What if I dont know the length?

Comment: If your loop executes variable number of time, say n, than do Integer[] ints = new Integer[n]; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { ints[i] = i; } and call new Loader().execute(ints); You can pass to execute() array of Integers with the variable length.

Comment: I've made edit, use transaction if possible, it increases the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the loop inside the task.

```
    Integer arr[] = new Integer[2];
    arr[0]=0;
    arr[1]=1;

    new Loader.execute(arr);

    @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

                foreach (Integer i : params)
                 db.insert(params[i]);
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: I have more works to do in the asynctask, and I have to stay inside the loop, but I cant figure out how to solve this issue

Comment: You can do what you want inside the loop anyway. Depends on what it is, you may need to use Handler to communicate with the main thread.